# Iterating over a changing sequence in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

Suppose we have syntax as follows:

```
for (i in sequence) {
  ...
  sequence <- append(sequence, i, after = 3)
}
```

But the code seems not to work properly because `sequence` is not updating within the brackets. I have come up with a similar decision using `while` loop instead. Is it possible to use `for` loop anyway?

Comment: What is in `sequence` before the `for` loop?

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover something like `3 5 9 7 1` (random uneven number row of n-elements)

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop in R only evaluates the `seq` value (`sequence` in your example) at the beginning.  So changing `sequence` in your loop will have no effect over how many times the loop will run.

For example,

```
sequence <- 1:2
for (i in sequence) {
  print(i)
  sequence <- 0
}
```

will print the numbers 1 and 2, and then will finish, with `sequence` containing a single zero.

This is described in the help page `?"for"`:

> The seq in a for loop is evaluated at the start of the loop; changing
> it subsequently does not affect the loop. If seq has length zero the
> body of the loop is skipped. Otherwise the variable var is assigned in
> turn the value of each element of seq. You can assign to var within
> the body of the loop, but this will not affect the next iteration.
> When the loop terminates, var remains as a variable containing its
> latest value.

Answer (score 1):

No, for loops in R can be considered a function call that iterates over the inputs "by value" (eg. by copying the input). Any change to the iterator sequence after start will leave the for-loop iteration unaffected. This is in general **good practice** as it drastically reduces bad coding practice and infinite loops. This is easily illustrated with a simple example:

```
idx <- 1:15
for(i in idx){
  idx <- head(idx, -1)
  cat('idx: ', idx, '\n')
  cat('i: ', i, '\n')
}
```

If you want to update the iterator your best bet is either `repeat` or `while` but be careful as it increases the potential for errors and unexpected infinite loops.

```
idx <- 1:15
while(length(idx) != 0){
  i <- head(idx, 1)
  idx <- tail(idx, -1)
  cat('idx: ', idx, '\n')
  cat('i: ', i, '\n')
}
```